# After switch domain, some parts of my site still point to my old domain

Tags: multisite, redirect, migration, subdomains, domain

I followed the first two passes of this guide: https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/

So I edited `wp-config.php` and `functions.php`.

The site seemed to work in the most of parts, but if I click on some parts of the site, they redirect to my old domain, so the switch of domain is not fully completed.

What could be the reason?

I am using Elementor page builder with Neve theme.

**Edit:**

Just realized that Elementor has itself a tool that does the replacing of urls. So I used it and everything worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Some themes use url in /wp-admin settings menu url. Please also change this. And another problem is full-urls in your db. You should change these urls in db.

*https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/#changing-the-url-directly-in-the-database*

BTW, if you are using phpmyadmin, search old url in all tables (you can search all tables when click the db not any table and you will see search tab right hand) and manually change.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Just realized that Elementor has itself a tool that does the replacing of urls. So I used it and everything worked :)